# PropertyAcess : Define condition values for label in PropertyAcess

Tags: gwt, gxt

I have a model called Field which has id and label.

I have defined PropertyAcess as below and it works. I would like to change it in such a way that I can show label based on condition ie if field.getLabel() is null, use field.getId() as label. How can I acheieve that

```
interface FieldProperties extends PropertyAccess<Field> {
  ModelKeyProvider<Field> id();

  LabelProvider<Field> label();

  @Path("label")
  ValueProvider<Field, String> labelProp(); 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `PropertyAccess` tool is meant to make it easy to quickly build `ValueProvider`, `ModelKeyProvider`, and `LabelProvider` instances that are based on a specific getter/setter on a bean-like object. If you don't want *just* access to a single property, then implement the interface directly.

In your case, since you want a `LabelProvider` that returns getLabel() unless it is null, then `getId()`, you might do something like this:

```
public LabelOrIdLabelProvider implements LabelProvider<Field> {
    @Override
    public String getLabel(Object item) {
        return item.getLabel() == null ? item.getId() : item.getLabel();
    }
}
```

If you want custom behavior, build it out yourself to do exactly what you need. If you just want the simple behavior of reading a single getter, the `PropertyAccess` is there to help save you a few lines of code.